# Query for parent-to-child (lookup)

Tags: soql, subquery

I need to query all the related children of an object, the connection is via a lookup relationship.

Query as follows to illustrate:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Orders) 
FROM Invoice__c
```

Error message:

> sObject type 'Invoice__r' is not supported. If you are attempting to
>   use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: [Using Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using)

Comment: I think that the parent-to-child query only works with a master relationship not with a regular lookup relationship :(

Comment: That is not correct, @Cubancoffee. You can perform parent-child SOQL with both master-detail and lookup relationships. You need to look at the lookup field between these objects to get the **relationship name** and use that name with `__r` in your child subquery.

Comment: I also added the __r but I still have the same issue. It only works for master-detail relationships :(. I know is asking a lot but, Can you maybe add an answer with your solution? just to make sure I am using the same query as you suggested.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct relationship name?  Can you post a screenshot of the lookup field in edit mode so the relationship name field is displayed?

Answer (score 4):

You should at least query a field from Invoice__c parent object, like below:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Orders__r)   //check the proper API name of the child Order object 
FROM Invoice__c
```

Check the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) from Sfdc docs for better understanding.

Comment: Since that's a custom relationship, there's going to be an `__r` involved.

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work. Error message as follows:

Didn't understand relationship 'Orders' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: @DavidReed yeah, that's right. I'm updating my answer :)